# Measure CPU/memory consumption

Tags: c++, memory, time, cpu, cpu-usage

I used this for measure the time execution in c++:

```
struct timeval t1, t2;
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
int milliSeconds = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000;
```

But I want to measure also the cpu / memory consumption. How can I do this?

Comment: Check `getrusage()`, it's much better to know how much your specific process took instead of total real time.

Comment: You will need to specify what is the target OS, what kind of CPU usage do you want to know? Cycles count? Time spent as runnable? Clock time? Running time? Usage in percentage?

Comment: Not sure it's what you want, but if you're looking for a micro-benchmark library, try out this one by Google: https://github.com/google/benchmark. It measures CPU-time per iteration, as well as other things.

Comment: @LiranFunaro Sorry, I want usage in percentage and if it is possible, running time. Can you help me?

Comment: @AlexisWilke thank you so much! For memory It's good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the percentage of the used CPU, you can use  [Alexsis Wilke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212378/alexis-wilke) advice for using [`getrusage()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) and divide by the total runtime as you calculated in your question.
This will give you the average percentage of the used CPU for a single CPU. If you are using many processors, you can also divide by the number of processors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!